# How do I expose interfaces Property via WCF in VB.NET?

Tags: wcf, properties, service

In C# I can do this to expose a property via WCF

```
[ServiceContractAttribute()]
public interface IFoo
{
  int Length
  { 
    [OperationContract()] get;
    [OperationContract()] set;
  }
}
```

I have to do it that way since OperationContract decorates a method but not a property. I'm working with a legacy interface that I can't easily change to remove the use of properties.

How do I perform the same thing in vb.net, I can't figure out what property syntax I would use in the interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately (as far as I know) VB uses a very simple property syntax for interfaces that does not allow you to specify attributes on the `get` or `set`.

Comment: I have an existing interface I have to provide remote access to. In my C# example provided, I can define the operation contract on the property getter and setter. In a vb.net interface, it doesn't seem to allow me to put attributes on the getter and setter of a property defined in the interface.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem - I wish it was better news!

Answer (score -2):

```
  <OperationContract(AsyncPattern:=True)>
```